# Filter values in drop down of AttributeInspector (SmartEditor Widget)

Tags: filter, wab

I am using AttributeInpector for displaying attributes associated with a Polygon in Feature Layer in ArcGIS ESRI.

I want to filter values in drop down for an attribute which can have one value out of the multiple possible values, displayed in AttributeInspector based on selected value of other drop down.

Is it possible to filter out values in AttributeInspector?
Parent field and child field are domain. Esri web doesn't support contingent-values.

Any idea how can I filter child field?